# Memory leak from malloc through tokenise function in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks, tokenize

I'm encountering a memory leak when I exit my program (found using valgrind) from the tokenize function I've written. Outside of this function, after I assign the tokens to other variables, I call free(tokens) where appropriate, but this doesn't fix the problem. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Code:

```
/**
 * Splits user input into an array of tokens.
 **/
char ** tokenize(const char * s, int * n)
{
   /* Sets array of strings and allocates memory, sized appropriately. */
   int i;
   char * token;   
   char ** tokens = malloc((BUF_LEN + EXTRA_SPACES) *sizeof(*token));
   char buf[BUF_LEN];
   strncpy(buf, s, BUF_LEN);

   /* Defines first token by a whitespace. */
   token = strtok(buf, " ");

   i = 0;
   /* While loop defines all consequent tokens also with a whitespace. */
   while (token)
   {
      tokens[i] = malloc((strlen(token)+EXTRA_SPACES) *sizeof(*token));
      strncpy(tokens[i], token, strlen(token));
      i++;
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
   * n = i;
   return tokens;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `free`...

Comment: @Idos After I use my tokens elsewhere in my code, I call `free(tokens);` as necessary. Should I be calling `free` inside this function?

Comment: @reyzay You can have a function that does `free` for you, please have a look at my answer that also checks with valgrind that there is no leak anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a function to `free` your array and checked it with valgrind that there is no memory leak.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
size_t BUF_LEN = 32;
int EXTRA_SPACES = 16;
int length = 0;
char ** tokenize(const char * s, int * n)
{
    /* Sets array of strings and allocates memory, sized appropriately. */
    int i;
    char * token;
    char ** tokens = malloc((BUF_LEN + EXTRA_SPACES) *sizeof(*token));
    char buf[BUF_LEN];
    strncpy(buf, s, BUF_LEN);

    /* Defines first token by a whitespace. */
    token = strtok(buf, " ");

    i = 0;
    /* While loop defines all consequent tokens also with a whitespace. */
    while (token)
    {
        tokens[i] = malloc((strlen(token)+EXTRA_SPACES) *sizeof(*token));
        strncpy(tokens[i], token, strlen(token));
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        length++;
    }
    * n = i;
    return tokens;
}

/* deallocates an array of arrays of char*, calling free() on each */
void free_argv(char **argv, unsigned rows) {
    for (unsigned row = 0; row < rows; row++) {

        free(argv[row]);
    }
    free(argv);
}

int main ()
{
int i = 12;
    char **  ch = tokenize("abc", &i);
    free_argv(ch, (unsigned) length);

}
```

Output

```
 valgrind ./a.out 
==28962== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28962== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28962== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28962== Command: ./a.out
==28962== 
==28962== 
==28962== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28962==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28962==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 67 bytes allocated
==28962== 
==28962== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==28962== 
==28962== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28962== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's great. I'll start writing and see how I go.

Comment: Well, still having problems, but now I understand the theory behind how I should've been going about `free`ing memory. So this answer worked for me. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

> I call free(tokens) where appropriate

`free(tokens);` is not enough, you must call `free` for each allocated item:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    free(tokens[i]);
}
free(tokens);
```